# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

what i need

- i need to call onclick function from php file.

php code

```
$content .= '
            <div class="evt_date" >

            <meta itemprop="startDate" content="'.$data[$k]['startDate'].'">
            <meta itemprop="endDate" content="'.$data[$k]['endDate'].'">
            <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-listing"  onClick="favaorite('.$data[$k]['id'].',"'.$data[$k]['city'].'","'.$data[$k]['country'].'","'.$data[$k]['event_url'].'")">Addtofavorite</button>
            </span>
```

javascript code

```
function favaorite(sess_id,city,country,event_url)
 {
 console.log(sess_id);
 console.log(city);
 console.log(country);
 console.log(event_url);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but _"favaorite"_ is actually spelled _"favorite"_

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
$content .= '<div class="evt_date" >
             <meta itemprop="startDate" content="'.$data[$k]['startDate'].'">
             <meta itemprop="endDate" content="'.$data[$k]['endDate'].'">
             <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-listing"  onClick="favaorite('.$data[$k]['id'].',\''.$data[$k]['city'].'\',\''.$data[$k]['country'].'\',\''.$data[$k]['event_url'].'\')">Addtofavorite</button>
             </span>';
```

Comment: but id "t understand logic adding (\',\'') in php

Comment: Because compiler is thinking it is end of the method, as you gave double quote. check for this piece of code you wrote - `onClick="favaorite('.$data[$k]['id'].',"`. Compiler is checking this is the whole method, and it is searching for the closing brace now.

Comment: Even you can use strip `\` with double quote, but better would be with single quote. We are just stripping the single quote here.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the multiple quotes, ie quotes within quotes.

```
$click_fnt = "favaorite($data[$k]['id'],$data[$k]['city'],$data[$k]['country'],$data[$k]['event_url'])";
```

and add it to your code

```
$content .= '<div class="evt_date" >
             <meta itemprop="startDate" content="'.$data[$k]['startDate'].'">
             <meta itemprop="endDate" content="'.$data[$k]['endDate'].'">
             <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-listing"  onClick="'.$click_fnt.'">Addtofavorite</button>
             </span>';
```

This way it wont confuse the compiler nor the programmer.